# Black Screen After Logging Into Any Window Manager

Tags: window-manager, graphics, desktop-environment, tiling-wm

I am trying to install a tiling window manager on my **Acer nitro 7 AN715-51** laptop

```
CPU: Intel Core i7-9750H CPU
GPU: GeForce GTX 1650
OS:  Pop!_OS 19.10
OS type: 64-bit
```

I tried to install **awesomeWM** using `sudo apt install awesome`, then I rebooted and logged into **AwesomeWM**.
At this point I was greeted with a black screen.

I tried:

- Opening a terminal with the shortcut, nothing happened.
- Installing different window managers to see if **awesomeWM** was the problem, but I had the same result.
- I tried installing the corresponding programming laungages (LUA for **awesomeWM**...etc)

I am guessing this has something to do with XORG or graphics drivers.

EDIT: I have the same problem when logging into various desktop enviroments; Enlightenment, LXQT, MATE and OpenBox do not work, although, Cinnamon and unity work

Comment: What do you mean to log into AwesomeWM? Did you do so via a display manager?

Comment: Yes. I log into AwesomeWM with GDM, The default display manager for pop OS instead of gnome, The default desktop environment.

Comment: Also, don't neglect Pop!_OS Support at http://pop.system76.com/docs , http://reddit.com/r/pop_os , chat.pop-os.org,

Comment: @K7AAY Thank you for the resources.